# My page is not scrolling even after applying all the methods I could find on web

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to scroll to the bottom of the page when I click **contacts** on the navbar
I have tried
 1. windows.scrollTo()
 2. windows.scrollBy()
 3. element.scrollIntoView();
 4. And all other methods that I could find
but the page does not scroll.
Here is my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/bvuayks8/1/
I have kept some content on the page so that it can be scrolled.
Here is the code

```js
// ------------------------------Getting the ids-----------------------------------------
var questionid = document.getElementById('question');
var contact = document.getElementById('contact');

// window.scrollTo(0,2000);


// ------------------------------Clear the browser storage--------------------------------
//localStorage.clear();
//sessionStorage.clear();

questionid.focus();

contact.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 1500);
  //alert('asdf');
})
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(../images/images/documentbackground.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/*-------------------------------------Main head------------------------------------------- */

.jumbotron {
  margin: 0;
  background: url(../images/a2.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.mainHead a {
  display: block;
  width: 7%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3BF44F;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color .7s;
}

.mainHead a:hover {
  background-color: #08B81B;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------NavBar--------------------------------------*/

.navbar {}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0 75px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.7s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #0bbc08;
  color: white;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------Login------------------------------------*/

.login {
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../images/images/back1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 -45%;
  /*transition: all 1s;*/
}

/*.login:hover{
 transition: all 1s;
 background-size: 150%;
}*/

.login h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.login .question {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.login .question input {
  width: 100%;
}

.login .button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

/*----------------------------------------Menu--------------------------------------------------*/

.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../images/how.jpg);
}

.menu button {
  transition: all .5s;
}

.menu .graduated:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu .interview:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu .tenthpass:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu .questions:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu .twpass:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu .register:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

/*-------------------------------------------CareerCounsellor---------------------------------------*/

.careerCounselor {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../images/a6.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.careerCounselor .heading,
.careerCounselor .examples {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.careerCounselor .row1 img {
  width: 55%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.careerCounselor .name {
  color: white;
}

.careerCounselor .post {
  color: #cbbf5a;
}

.careerCounselor .exp {
  color: white;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------Examples------------------------------------------*/

/*-------------------------------------------questionGuide---------------------------------------*/

.questionGuide {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../images/a2.jpg);
}

/*-------------------------------------------Videos---------------------------------------*/

/*-------------------------------------------Footer---------------------------------------*/

.footer {
  background-color: #91FB9D;
  text-align: center;
}

.footernav {
  width: 100%;
}

.footer .row {
  padding: 1% 10% 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homePagecss.css">
    <title>Career Guide</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <ul class="m-0 p-0 bg-success navbar">
        <li class="p-1"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="p-1"><a href="#">Interview</a></li>
        <li class="p-1"><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
        <li class="p-1"><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
        <li class="p-1" id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="login pt-2">
        <h3 class="mt-3">Your Career Is Your Life</h3>
        <div class="mt-4 question">
          <input id="question" type="text" class="rounded" name="question" placeholder="Type your question">
          <button id="askbtn" type="button" class="btn mt-1 btn-success button">ASK!</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu container">
        <div class="menuHeading">
          <h3 class="mt-3">How to choose your career</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 tenthpass">10th pass</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 twpass">12th pass</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 graduated">Graduated</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 register">Register</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 interview">Interview</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 questions">Questions</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>




      <div class="examples p-2 mt-3 font-weight-bold">HOW CAREER GUIDE CHANGING THE LIVES</div>
      <div class="row" style="display: flex;">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <p class="">Career Guidence made course choice simple and easy. I am happy i could make it to IIM-Indore</p>
          <img src="../images/a.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm ">
          <p class="">Career guidence towards food technology made mahima an example for her friends they can now look beyond the medicine</p>
          <img src="../images/b.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm ">
          <p class=""> Me and my dad found selection of stream after 10th very scientific and efficient Thenks to CareerGuide</p>
          <img src="../images/c.jpg" style="height: 60%;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row row2 w-100 p-3 mt-4 container">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <iframe style="border-width: 10px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yIW6eTU2oXY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <iframe style="border-width: 10px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FTiKWY2AbEw" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <iframe style="border-width: 10px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R7iN71uJcG0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer pt-3 rounded">
      <div class="footernav">
        <a href="about.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-light mr-3">About</button></a>
        <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-light mr-3">Contact Us</button></a>
        <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-light mr-3">Terms and Conditions</button></a>
        <a href="Login.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-light mr-3">Login</button></a>
        <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-light mr-3">Registration</button></a>
      </div>
      <div class="phone mt-3">
        <img src="../images/phone.png" width="20px" height="20px">
        <p class="d-inline-block">+919610085083</p>
      </div>
      <div class="links">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/twitter.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="mr-1" ></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/g+.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="mr-1" ></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/facebook.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="mr-1" ></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/img2.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="mr-1" ></a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <p>1105<br>Career Experts</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <p>551<br>Career Topics</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <p>1199<br>Career Questions</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <p>345,123<br>Students Impacted</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="homePage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you talking about smooth scrolling or just talking about jumping down to the bottom of the page? If it is the last one just set an id to the footer (e.g. `id="footer"`) and set your `href` attribute to (e.g.) `href="#footer"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need JavaScript for this , you can add one id in footer and simply call it on click of contact button as follow.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(../images/images/documentbackground.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/*-------------------------------------Main head------------------------------------------- */

.jumbotron {
  margin: 0;
  background: url(../images/a2.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.mainHead a {
  display: block;
  width: 7%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3BF44F;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color .7s;
}

.mainHead a:hover {
  background-color: #08B81B;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------NavBar--------------------------------------*/

.navbar {}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0 75px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.7s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #0bbc08;
  color: white;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------Login------------------------------------*/

.login {
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../images/images/back1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 -45%;
  /*transition: all 1s;*/
}

/*.login:hover{
 transition: all 1s;
 background-size: 150%;
}*/

.login h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.login .question {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.login .question input {
  width: 100%;
}

.login .button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

/*----------------------------------------Menu--------------------------------------------------*/

.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../images/how.jpg);
}

.menu button {
  transition: all .5s;
}

.menu .graduated:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu .interview:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu .tenthpass:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu .questions:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu .twpass:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu .register:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

/*-------------------------------------------CareerCounsellor---------------------------------------*/

.careerCounselor {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../images/a6.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.careerCounselor .heading,
.careerCounselor .examples {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.careerCounselor .row1 img {
  width: 55%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.careerCounselor .name {
  color: white;
}

.careerCounselor .post {
  color: #cbbf5a;
}

.careerCounselor .exp {
  color: white;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------Examples------------------------------------------*/

/*-------------------------------------------questionGuide---------------------------------------*/

.questionGuide {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../images/a2.jpg);
}

/*-------------------------------------------Videos---------------------------------------*/

/*-------------------------------------------Footer---------------------------------------*/

.footer {
  background-color: #91FB9D;
  text-align: center;
}

.footernav {
  width: 100%;
}

.footer .row {
  padding: 1% 10% 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homePagecss.css">
    <title>Career Guide</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <ul class="m-0 p-0 bg-success navbar">
        <li class="p-1"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="p-1"><a href="#">Interview</a></li>
        <li class="p-1"><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
        <li class="p-1"><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
        <li class="p-1" id="contact"><a href="#footer">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="login pt-2">
        <h3 class="mt-3">Your Career Is Your Life</h3>
        <div class="mt-4 question">
          <input id="question" type="text" class="rounded" name="question" placeholder="Type your question">
          <button id="askbtn" type="button" class="btn mt-1 btn-success button">ASK!</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu container">
        <div class="menuHeading">
          <h3 class="mt-3">How to choose your career</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 tenthpass">10th pass</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 twpass">12th pass</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 graduated">Graduated</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 register">Register</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 interview">Interview</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 questions">Questions</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>




      <div class="examples p-2 mt-3 font-weight-bold">HOW CAREER GUIDE CHANGING THE LIVES</div>
      <div class="row" style="display: flex;">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <p class="">Career Guidence made course choice simple and easy. I am happy i could make it to IIM-Indore</p>
          <img src="../images/a.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm ">
          <p class="">Career guidence towards food technology made mahima an example for her friends they can now look beyond the medicine</p>
          <img src="../images/b.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm ">
          <p class=""> Me and my dad found selection of stream after 10th very scientific and efficient Thenks to CareerGuide</p>
          <img src="../images/c.jpg" style="height: 60%;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row row2 w-100 p-3 mt-4 container">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <iframe style="border-width: 10px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yIW6eTU2oXY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <iframe style="border-width: 10px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FTiKWY2AbEw" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <iframe style="border-width: 10px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R7iN71uJcG0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="footer pt-3 rounded">
      <div class="footernav">
        <a href="about.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-light mr-3">About</button></a>
        <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-light mr-3">Contact Us</button></a>
        <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-light mr-3">Terms and Conditions</button></a>
        <a href="Login.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-light mr-3">Login</button></a>
        <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline-light mr-3">Registration</button></a>
      </div>
      <div class="phone mt-3">
        <img src="../images/phone.png" width="20px" height="20px">
        <p class="d-inline-block">+919610085083</p>
      </div>
      <div class="links">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/twitter.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="mr-1" ></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/g+.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="mr-1" ></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/facebook.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="mr-1" ></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/img2.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="mr-1" ></a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <p>1105<br>Career Experts</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <p>551<br>Career Topics</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <p>1199<br>Career Questions</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <p>345,123<br>Students Impacted</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="homePage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is really slick. But the thing that javascript is not working is really itching. I can't figure out why!

Comment: try adding setTimeout function

Answer (score 1):

If you want this using javascript than just add settimeout before call scroll function

```
contact.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 1500);
    },0)
    //alert('asdf');
})
```

Comment: Ya that WORKED. Why is setTimeout function necessary though?